# How to put the border of the entry field in red in case of wrong username or password?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

On the event of wrong username or password, change the border of the field in red instead of pop up in tkinter-python?

**Username code**

```
    self.username_entry = Entry(
        self.frame, bg="white", bd=2,
        font=self.USERNAME_ENTRY_FONT, relief=FLAT, highlightthickness=1, highlightbackground="black",
        selectbackground="yellow", highlightcolor='#4584F1')
    self.username_entry.place(
        relx=float(self.USERNAME_ENTRY_X) / self.VIRTUAL_WIDTH,
        rely=float(self.USERNAME_ENTRY_Y) / self.VIRTUAL_HEIGHT,
        relheight=float(60) / 768, relwidth=float(454)/1366)
    self.username_entry.bind('<FocusIn>', self.username_entry_handler)
    self.username_entry.bind('<FocusOut>', self.username_entry_handler)
```

**Pwd code**

```
    self.password_entry = Entry(
        self.frame, bg="white", bd=2,
        font=self.PASSWORD_ENTRY_FONT, relief=FLAT, highlightthickness=1, highlightbackground="black",
        selectbackground="yellow", show='*', highlightcolor='#4584F1')
    self.password_entry.place(
        relx=float(self.PASSWORD_ENTRY_X) / self.VIRTUAL_WIDTH,
        rely=float(self.PASSWORD_ENTRY_Y) / self.VIRTUAL_HEIGHT,
        relheight=float(60) / 768, relwidth=float(454)/1366)
    self.password_entry.bind('<FocusIn>', self.password_entry_handler)
    self.password_entry.bind('<FocusOut>', self.password_entry_handler)
    self.password_entry.bind("<Tab>", no_op)
```

Comment: Actually I should have asked for a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), with the import statements. What is really important here is what kind of Entry (tkinter or ttk) you are using.

Comment: I have used tkinter@ j_4321

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the options `highlightcolor` and `highlightbackground` to red for both entry fields if the login fails. Something like:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

def login():
    # login / passord checking
    right_login = False  

    if right_login:
        print('logged in')
    else:
        username_entry.configure(highlightbackground='red', highlightcolor='red')
        password_entry.configure(highlightbackground='red', highlightcolor='red')

username_entry = tk.Entry(root, bg="white", bd=2, relief='flat', 
                          highlightthickness=1, 
                          highlightbackground="black", 
                          selectbackground="yellow", 
                          highlightcolor='#4584F1')
password_entry = tk.Entry(root, bg="white", bd=2, relief='flat',
                          highlightthickness=1, highlightbackground="black",
                          selectbackground="yellow", show='*', 
                          highlightcolor='#4584F1')

username_entry.pack()
password_entry.pack()

tk.Button(root, text='Log In', command=login).pack()
root.mainloop()
```